# "Balls and box" type question

Tags: combinatorics

There are $N$ unique balls and a box with a capacity of $K$ ($N > K$). How many arrangements of balls that fill the box can you find such that no two arrangements contain a common pair of balls?

For example, if there are $6$ balls, labeled with numbers from $1$ to $6$, and a box with capacity $3$, we can find $4$ arrangements: $$(1,2,3),\,(2,4,5),\,(4,1,6),\,(5,3,6).$$ We can't add more from here since every ball has already been a neighbor with four other balls. Since the box's capacity is $3$, any other arrangements must have a pair of balls which are already in one of the arrangements above.

I could not find similar questions in this site.

Comment: How will there be any same pair of balls if all are unique>

Comment: Can you make your question more precise?  Usually such ball/urn questions don't have a concept of "neighbors".  Also, it's likely there is an answer to a similar question already on the site - feel free to take a look at the "Related" questions on the right!

Comment: (1,2,3), (1,4,5), (2,4,6)?

Comment: Thanks, I will change description.

Comment: @azamatm I edited the problem's redaction. Can you confirm that what I wrote is what you meant?

Comment: I’m pretty sure he means if say Balls 2 and 3 are in one possible combination then they cannot appear TOGETHER in another combination

Comment: @Anteater23 that's exactly what I meant

Answer (score 1):

Each ball can appear at most $\left \lfloor \frac {N-1}{K-1}\right \rfloor$ times because it is paired with $K-1$ balls each time it appears.  The total number of balls among the arrangements is then at most $N\left \lfloor \frac {N-1}{K-1}\right \rfloor$.  We use up $K$ each time, so the total number of arrangements is at most $\left \lfloor \frac NK\left \lfloor \frac {N-1}{K-1}\right \rfloor\right \rfloor$  There is enough freedom that this should be achievable.  In your example this is $\left \lfloor \frac 63\left \lfloor \frac {6-1}{3-1}\right \rfloor\right \rfloor=2\left\lfloor \frac 52\right\rfloor=4$

Comment: I think this is leaving out huge chunks of reasoning.

Comment: @URL:  I think the reasoning is clear giving the upper bound.  What it does not do is show that the upper bound is achievable.  Do you agree?

Comment: Yeah, hopefully that gap can be fixed.